# How to solve unexpected token import

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Below is my code

```
import * as errorHandler from "errorhandler";

import { default as app } from "./express";
import * as cors from "cors";
/**
 * Error Handler. Provides full stack - remove for production
 */
app.use(errorHandler());
```

I have got an error that looks like this below

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as errorHandler from "errorhandler";
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I would be thankful if some help is offered for this solution

Comment: As of now you cannot directly use `ES6` module system syntax (`import/export`) in Node. Either use experimental support for that as mentioned in one of answers. OR use a transpiler like `babel` [More info](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) that basically converts this code to `commonJS` module syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does not support ECMAScript-style modules by default (which is what `import` is). Run your app with `--experimental-modules` or convert to using `require()` instead. More information can be found [in the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).